# How can I use CssResources in UiBinder a generated Cell?

Tags: java, javascript, css, gwt, uibinder

I want to generate a Cell for a CellWidget with the UiBinder (UiRenderer). What I did to generate the cell is in **MyCell.java**:

```
public class MyCell implements AbstractCell<MyDto> {

    public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

        @Source({Css.DEFAULT_CSS })
        Css css();
    }

    public interface Css extends CssResource {

        String DEFAULT_CSS = "test/MyStyle.css";
        String test();
    }

    interface MyUiRenderer extends UiRenderer {
        void render(SafeHtmlBuilder sb, String name, SafeStyles styles);
    }

    private static MyUiRenderer renderer = GWT.create(MyUiRenderer.class);

    Resources resources = GWT.create(Resources.class);

    @Override
    public void render(SafeHtmlBuilder safeHtmlBuilder, MyDto model) {

        SafeStyles style = SafeStylesUtils.fromTrustedString(resources.css().test().toString());
        renderer.render(safeHtmlBuilder, model.getName(), style);

    }

}
```

My **MyCell.ui.xml** file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">

<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'>

    <ui:with field="name" type="java.lang.String" />
    <ui:with field='styles' type='com.google.gwt.safecss.shared.SafeStyles'/> 


    <div style="{styles}"><ui:text from="{name}" /></div>


</ui:UiBinder>
```

**MyStyle.css**:

```
.test {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  ...
}
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] [mobile] - Rebinding test.client.app.MyCell.MyUiRenderer
    [DEBUG] [mobile] - Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinderGenerator
        [ERROR] [mobile] - java.lang.String required, but {styles} returns com.google.gwt.safecss.shared.SafeStyles: <div style='{styles}'> (:9)
[ERROR] [mobile] - Deferred binding failed for 'test.client.app.MyCell.MyUiRenderer'; expect subsequent failures
[ERROR] [mobile] - (GWT.java:72) 2014-06-08 17:15:05,214 [FATAL] Uncaught Exception:
```

Then I tried to this:

```
<ui:with field="styles" type="java.lang.String" />
```

in my UiBinder but it does not work.

**How can I use css style from a CssResource in my UiRenderer?**

Comment: I didn't notice it. Let me try with `UiRenderer`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="{styles}">
```

Two problems here. First, in order to change the style of an element, you have two options, setting the style attribute to include specific properties, or set the class attribute to point to a class you’ve defined in CSS somewhere. So, you really want to set `class` here, not `style`.

Second, you created a css class called "test", but are assigning here just the whole interface, styles. Instead, reference styles.test:

```
<div class="{styles.test}" />
```

---

Edit: one final piece you may be missing (but since "This does not work" is so vague I don't know if this is your actual problem): I don't see any call to `ensureInjected()` in your example. Make sure you call this on your `Css` instance before using it.

Comment: This does not work. Please have a look at my code maybe you overlooked something. Thank you!

Comment: Colin is right on both counts. If it does not work, post a new error message.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put .asString after styles in the xml:

```
<div style="{styles.asString}"><ui:text from="{name}" /></div>
```